# How can I access these elements using jQuery to add and remove a class on click?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, siblings

I have many of these unordered lists which are being dynamically created through a for loop. The problem is that I haven't been able to target ONLY the elements in this ul, it has been changing the class of active for each one. I'm having a hard time understanding what's a sibling, what's a cousin etc. I've tried closest(), siblings(), prev(), find() and some different combinations of them but can't seem to work it out.
http://jsfiddle.net/T3cm4/

Here's the HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="button active">Option 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="button">Option 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="button">Option 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="button">Option 4</a</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
var set_active = $('.button');
set_active.on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var others = set_active.not($this);

  $this.addClass('active');
  others.removeClass('active');

// this will remove all other active 
// states, what do I need to add so 
// it only selects the siblings?

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reduce it to just this:

```
$('.button').click(function () {
    $(this).parents('ul').find('a.button').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/T3cm4/2/)**

This assigns the click handler to your links with the button class (`.button`). Upon clicking, it goes up to the first parent `ul` it finds, then it searches down for all `a.button` element children and removes the active class from all of them. Then it applies the active class to the element that was just clicked.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Is it considered best practice to use .click() instead of .on('click')? Or is it just preference at this point.

Comment: `.click()` is just a shortcut for `.on('click')`. I use on() more when I'm adding elements dynamically and need to delegate.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind it

```
$('.button').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.button').removeClass('active'); //remove all classes
    $(this).addClass('active');  //add it to the clicked one
});
```

Comment: I didn't -1 you but your answer has the same issues that the OP's code does -- it removes the highlight from all the lists, not only the one clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `this`, is a `<a>` element. It is the child of a `<li>` element and has no siblings. Siblings would be other children of the *same* `<li>`. What you are trying to access are the children of the siblings of the parent of `<this>`. A basic way of selecting these, and then removing the active class from them, would be to use the following line:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().children().removeClass('active');
```

`$(this).parent()` returns the single `<li>` that is the direct parent of the `<a>`, `$(this).parent().siblings()` returns an array of all of the *other* children of the `<ul>` element that that `<li>` is a child of, and `$(this).parent().siblings().children()` returns an array of all of the children of those elements, which is the array of all of the elements you are looking for. There are many other ways of selecting all of these elements, as you can see in the rest of the answers.

It is possible, in any of these selectors, to filter down what is returned by adding an argument to the method. For example, if we wanted only siblings of our parent `<li>` that had the class "foo", we could use `$(this).parent().siblings('.foo')` to get an array of those elements.

`.find(selector)` will dig through all of the descendants (children, grand children, great grand children and such) and return an array of all elements that match the selector, which would be something like the `'.foo'` selector we looked at as a way of getting siblings with the "foo" class in the prior example.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting others as such:

```
var others = set_active.parents('ul:eq(0)').find('.button').not($this);
```

Comment: @coryjacik - are you referring to the ul:eq(0)?  That is there in case you have other lists with buttons which you do not want to affect.  So only the buttons in the list which was clicked will be affected.  If you do not want this restriction, than remove the :eq(0)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul li a').first().addClass('active');
$('ul li a').on('click', function() {
  var parents = $(this).parents('ul');
  $('li a', parents).removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Add active class to clicked element remove from others.  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T3cm4/3/)

```
var set_active = $('.button');
set_active.on('click', function() {
  set_active.parents("ul:first").find(".active").removeClass("active");   
  $(this).addClass('active');
```

});